# proper rest uri format for passing in an array of ints?

Tags: rest

I need to get a purchase ticket report based on a set of delivery ID's.  For example:

- A GET uri of /purchase-ticket-report
- Delivery ID's of [1,3,5,7]

What would be a proper way to represent this in a REST implementation?  It doesn't seem to map cleanly to a standard REST request.  Would you recommend falling back to a query string param like:

GET /purchase-ticket-report?deliveryIds=1,3,5,7

^^^ I'm not even totally sure if it's valid for me to pass a qs param in that format.  Another option might be to pass the int array through a property in a json request body.  How would you handle this scenario in a REST implementation?

Answer (score 0):

> Would you recommend falling back to a query string param like:

```
 GET /purchase-ticket-report?deliveryIds=1,3,5,7
```

That looks great

1. It conform to the production rules of [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A)
2. It's easy to recreate using an HTML form
3. It's easily described as a [URI Template](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) that will be understood by any template library with level 4 support.

> Another option might be to pass the int array through a property in a json request body.

That's a last resort - it might be necessary if lists can have so many elements that you start blowing through [URI length limits](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.12).  But if you can keep the ids in the URI, that will make [caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234) much easier.